Tax question regarding a house
I am about to be given (gifted?) One third of my parents home, long story.
I'm guessing that will be an approximate market value to me of 125k, house is worth just under 400k.
So, will I owe tax on that?
Parents are both living.
We're not going to sell the house
Hmm, that's all I can think of right now
Thanks

What country are you in? Tax laws differ between different countries.

Note that in the US, being gifted a house rather than inheriting it can have very significant tax consequences. I would talk to an estate planning attorney if the plan is for them to stay in the house until you inherit it.

If person A gives person B a gift, then there is no tax liability, of any kind to person B. However, person A may have to file a gift tax return and maybe a generation  skipping tax return.
So if your parents give you 1/3 of a house worth 400K and it is a completed gift then they are required to file a gift tax return also known as form 709. It is unlikely that they will have to pay any gift tax, depending on what kind of gifts  they have given in the past, but it will generate an add back. That means, that it may result in paying estate tax when they die.
By the way, if you gift an appreciated asset to somebody you do not get a cost basis reset but if you inherit it, you do. Hence, it might be better for you and your parents to wait until after they die for you to inherit the house.
Note: I am assuming that this house is in the United States.

That assumes US tax laws and may be very wrong for other countries.

In the UK there will be no tax to pay at the time, but if the giver dies within seven years of the gift then it may become retrospectively liable for inheritance tax. However, there’s a £350K per person IHT exemption for one’s primary residence, which can be transferred between spouses, so a tax bill would be unlikely in this situation.

If the parents continue to live in the house then this may well be a gift with reservation of benefits and that is not a gift at all in the eyes of the law.

In Slovakia, gift tax has been abolished in 2004. However, if you were to sell the house, you have to include the profit¹ into your income and pay an income tax, unless you wait 5 years (and other conditions are met, e.g. it has not been assigned as a business property, esp. relevant if your parents or you are self-employed).
¹ Defined as the difference between the selling price and the buying price minus eligible expenses, where the buying price is to be determined depending on the exact condition of when and how your parents acquired the house.
This is a TL;DR answer - there are many exceptions and technicalities. Consult your tax adviser, unless you are sure (or better, even if your are sure).
Though, to answer to the letter, technically speaking, you will (almost) always be liable for a real estate tax. The amount is set by the municipality this time, but these are on the order of tens of € (and depend on the area, not the value), thus quite negligible compared to the price of the house.
